# Confidence interval for sum of forecasts

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, forecasting, vector-autoregression

I've got two time series, let's say X and Y. They are correlated. I can obtain forcast for X and for Y separatly (I'm using VAR model) and confidence intervals for them. Then I would like to make a forcast for X+Y, so I'm just adding prediction for X and Y. But what should I do to obtain the confidence interval?

Comment: Do you refer to confidence intervals of [prediction intervals](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/7)..?

Comment: I've got two tables which consists of prediction and confidence interval for each point of time. And I want to join them by adding. I'm sure that I shouldn't add confidence intervals though.